# Why is the production cross section for 3rd generation squarks (stops) so much smaller than for 1st and 2nd generation?

Tags: supersymmetry, scattering-cross-section, pair-production

In the plot below we see that the production cross section for 3rd generation squarks (i.e. top squarks) at a hadron collider is about a factor 10 smaller than that for 1st and 2nd generation squarks ("light squarks") of the same mass. My question is why this is the case.

After looking through [this theory paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.4771.pdf), I can imagine several potential reasons:

- the squark-cross section line in the plot lumps together all light squark generations  (may be wrong), so it's partly just because there is only one top squark but 5 light squarks
- there is no t-channel contribution

Are these correct? Are there further reasons? Which one is the most important?

[image: Prospino cross sections for LHC]

Comment: fundamentally they are more unstable and require higher energies to be made at all

Comment: Not sure what you mean? As we don't know their mass, we cannot say which one requires more energy to be produced.

Comment: You already established that they have the same mass, therefore, the more unstable (with the same mass) would require higher energy!

Comment: Sorry, I still fail to understand this argument. I am asking about the difference in the cross section. The (center-of-mass) energy is fixed.